# Using Java Regex, how to check if a String contains any "|" but not "||"

Tags: java, regex

Basically my problem is to validate a boolean expression, so I do not want a single or more than two `&` or `|` to appear between other expressions.

Ex. I want `Pattern.compile(Regex).matcher("A || B").find()` to be `false`, but `Pattern.compile(Regex).matcher("A | B").find()` and `Pattern.compile(Regex).matcher("A ||| B").find()` to be `true`, is there any `Regex` that can achieve this?

Comment: ... Try `\ba\b`

Comment: @user85421, you are right, however in my case, I do not care about bit-wise OR/AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match 'a' or 'aaa' but not 'aa' you need a regex with a negative look-ahead; e.g.

```
    ((?<!a)a(?!a))|(a{3,})
```

That says "find either an 'a' that is not preceded by an 'a' and not followed by an 'a', or a sequence of 3 or more 'a'`".

However, `find` with the above regex and this string "a bb aa" will give a hit.  If you want to check that the string contains some 'a's and no 'aa', you will need to test the two conditions separately.

To match '|' characters instead of 'a' characters, replace 'a' with '\|' in the above.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex `\\s\\|(\\|\\|)*\\s` for your use-case. 
As pipe `(|)`is a special character for regex, so we need to escape it`(\|)`. Below is the regex explanation

1. `\\s` - Space start
2. `\\|` - Atleast one `|` should be present
3. `(\\|\\|)*` - Then `|` should be present in multiple of 2
4. `\\s` - Space end

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String regex = "\\s\\|(\\|\\|)*\\s";
       System.out.println(Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("A || B").find());
       System.out.println(Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("A | B").find());
       System.out.println(Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("A ||| B").find());
   }
   ```

This pattern assumes that `|` will have space before and after it. If there is a use-case where string doesn't have space before and after `|`, you can try out `\b` word boundary in the regex and see if it helps

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I should have stated my question cleared, I have changed the question, this would work for my original question, but not really for my actual problem, can you re-look my problem again?  I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

The following regex matches on either 1 or 3 or more of | or & :

```
([^|]\\|[^|])|([^&]&[^&])|[|&]{3,}
```

This gives the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = {"A|B", "A||B", "A|||B", "A&B", "A&&B", "A&&&B", "A&&&&&&&B"};
    String regex = "([^|]\\|[^|])|([^&]&[^&])|[|&]{3,}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Arrays.asList(strings)
        .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + ": " + pattern.matcher(x).find()));
}
```

Output:

```
A|B: true
A||B: false
A|||B: true
A&B: true
A&&B: false
A&&&B: true
A&&&&&&&B: true
```

Note that | and & are known as bitwise operators and are valid in Java. To match on actual invalid Java, matching on the following would do:

```
[|&]{3,}
```